# getting error while converting .apk file to jar file

Tags: android, jar, apk

I am trying to convert .apk to jar for this I used below link
http://androidorigin.blogspot.in/2011/02/dex-format-to-jar-format.html

but now I m getting error.
as:-

```
this cmd is deprecated, use the d2j-dex2jar if possible
dex2jar version: translator-0.0.9.13
dex2jar Health.apk -> Health_dex2jar.jar
. while process file: [Health.apk]
. ROOT cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'Health.apk' does not exist
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:56)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:40)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.reader.DexFileReader.readDex(DexFileReader.java:150)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main.doFile(Main.java:63)
at com.googlecode.dex2jar.v3.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Done.
```

can anyone help me..

Comment: `this cmd is deprecated, use the d2j-dex2jar if possible`

Comment: Can you please tell me how I used this d2j-dex2jar tool.
I have downloaded it,I m using window 8.

Comment: I cannot (but @MrYanDo's answer appears to). It's several versions of the tool since I've done anything with it, but occassionally I would find an apk that would fail to convert, and an update of the tool would address it. If you're using the latest version and the d2j batch file doesn't help, you may need to alert the tool maintainer.

Answer (score 6):

Download [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/detail?name=dex2jar-0.0.9.13.zip&can=2&q=) at [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/)'s website.

Extract the files inside.

Drag your apk into a file name called `d2j-dex2jar.bat` and a your converted jar should appear at where your apk file is located.

Answer (score 0):

You should first rename your app.apk to app.zip. Then extract the zip to get a class.dex file. Move the file to the dex2file directory . Then try to convert dex file to jar. That's why it is called dex2jar.